# Who built the LEGO structures for the film "Elf"?

Tags: popular-culture

My daughter greatly enjoyed the look on my face when the guy destroyed Buddy's LEGO models in the film *Elf*. She wishes she had a picture of me.

The question is: Does anybody know who built the LEGO models for the film? Was it a LUG?

Comment: I think I audibly gasped when I saw that.  It still makes me cringe - all that beautiful work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to an [interview with Elf director Jon Favreau](http://movies.about.com/cs/elf/a/elfjonfavreau_2.htm), the Lego City set was built in-house by the Rusty Smith's art department.

The [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0319343/companycredits) for the movie thanks The LEGO Group for the permission to use the LEGO logo and trademarks but has no mention of any further involvement in set design.

Comment: I'm sure I've read somewhere that they had to do it in one take, as it would've taken too long to re-assemble the models again!